# Can Silverlight access USB port

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, silverlight, google-chrome, usb

I'm developing web application using MVC3 and the requirement is to access USB port. if not possible is there other way or workaround for accessing port using web browser. Please send me a sample link.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might find more answers if you provided detail on why your App required access to a USB port. If this Intranet, then you are talking Corporate and you have more control over the Client side. If this is Internet, it's hopeless (or should be).

Answer (score 0):

Yes - it is possible. Silverlight 5 can access the Win32 API using PInvoke (platform invocation). The Silverlight application must be a trusted application.

Here's an example (there are lots of others, Google it):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2011/09/27/pinvoke-in-silverlight5-and-net-framework.aspx